# show conditional buttons using v-if inside a v-for in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, v-for

I want to show conditional buttons inside a v-for loop using v-if (only when category_id=1):
this is the vuejs part:

```html
<div class="w3-margin-bottom" v-for="category in categorys" v-bind:key="category.category_id">
  <div class="w3-quarter w3-button">
      <i class="w3-small" v-if="category.category_id='1'">
          <button class="w3-button w3-green">Sauce Blanche</button>
          <button class="w3-button w3-green">Sauce Rouge</button>
      </i>
      <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16">
        <div class="w3-clear">{{ category.category_des }}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript part:

```js
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      categorys: [],
      category_id: null,
      category_des: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getCategory: function () {
      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Category/").then((response) => {
        this.categorys = response.data;
      });
    },
```

Comment: try like this `v-if="category.category_id === '1'`

Comment: You've just got a typo in your `v-if`, `=` needs to be `==` or `===`. Always double check your equal signs, this is a really easy mistake to make!

Answer (score 3):

```
<template v-if="category.category_id === '1'">
  --buttons-- 
</template>
```

This assumes category_id is a string. Leave off the small quotes if it is a number.

Answer (score 3):

`v-if="category.category_id = '1'"` is always `true`, cause you used assign operator (`=`), instead of `equality operator` (`==`) or reference equality operator (`===`).

Change this to this instead:
`v-if="category.category_id === '1'"`